# How to remove bootstrap media query, which is installed by node package manager(npm)

Tags: html, css, angular2-template

I have to remove bootstrap media query in my project, project setup by using node package manager(npm). I need bootstrap only for desktop, so when it goes on small screen, element are break down according to tablet & mobile screen.
Please refer the screen shot:-

For desktop: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xec14.png, Looking good.

For mobile: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xERtA.png, Break all element

**Problem statement:** When remove the media query from node-module it will installed again when run the "npm install" command.

[variable.scss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eES0w.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could use Sass to customize the media queries https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/#sass-options

Comment: This is my comman sass file for scss variables, can you explain how can I remove, default responsive behavior form there.
Refer the variable.scss file link below